# Cannot change color of navigation bar title text

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    let attr: NSMutableDictionary! = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attr
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

It is said that

```
'Cannot assign value of type 'NSMutableDictionary!' to type '[String : AnyObject]?''
```

on this line

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attire
```

and if I change it to

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attr as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Although it has no error, but it can change the text's color. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can change color of title text navigation bar, for app in general.
Just add this at your **AppDelegate.swift** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: Hi @postman99 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: This didn't work for me. My title is still black, trying to change it to white. No error messages, doesn't work if I try to do it pragmatically or in storyboard. It's always black. Been happening since last xcode update.